# Usage of the attachHttpServer feature in Mosca

Tags: node.js, http, mqtt, mosca

I have read about the attachHttpServer feature in Mosca,
https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets

Basically we create a mosca server and an http server and attach the http server to Mosca. After that how do we really use it? Will REST requests coming to the http server be redirected to mosca? How does the connection, pubsub take place?

Any example use case on how this can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosca is using the httpServer to handle the websocket handshake in order to support MQTT over Websockets. This is for use with things like the Paho [javascript client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/).

This is not a HTTP REST to MQTT bridge.

You can attach your own endpoints to the httpServer so you can provide your own REST API or server up static content that will use the Paho client to connect to the mosca broker in order to consume and publish messages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just so that I understand this correctly, I have to create a Mosca server and Http server and attach the Http server to Mosca. Then I can create a REST endpoint in the file for the Http server. When I get an Http request, I can use the Paho client code to send the data received in Http REST service to the Mosca publish API. But since clients are connected over http rest (asynchronous), will they retain the websocket connection to receive data from mqtt whenever someone publishes on a topic

Comment: No, The paho client is used in the browser to connect to the broker. The HTTP server can be used to serve the paho client .js file and the rest of the page that hosts it along with any REST interfaces you may also need.

Comment: Still didnt get the purpose of attaching the http server to the mosca server. Paho client sends request to http server, what is Mosca's role in this? Does the http server automatically forward the request to the mqtt server and the request hits the publish, connect etc. methods?

Comment: The httpServer is only there to do the Websocket handshake

Comment: Thanks for the clarification